# Delete rows after comparing csv files (pandas, csv, python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

i'm trying to compare two csv files and delete rows from the second file if "Group" value does not exist as "Category 2" element in file 1. however, i don't have too much experience with this so i'm not sure about my approach. i have been messing around with pandas a little bit and also tried a ton of other things. how do i improve on this code so that i can compare two columns with different headings. currently, no lines are printed since i believe entire rows are compared? the outputs below should help to clarify things. thanks in advance.

```
with open('file1.csv', 'r') as t1, open('file2.csv', 'r') as t2:
    fileone = t1.readlines()
    filetwo = t2.readlines()

with open('update.csv', 'w') as outFile:
    for line in filetwo:
        if line in fileone:
            outFile.write(line)
```

file 1

```
All Lists                   
List 1                  
Category 1  Category 2  Category 3  Category 4  Category 5  Category 6
            element1            x   
            element2            x   
            element3            x   
            element4            x   
            element5            x   
List 2                  
Category 1  Category 2  Category 3  Category 4  Category 5  Category 6
            card1           x   
            card2           x   
            card3           x   
            card4           x   
            card5           x   
List 3                  
Category 1  Category 2  Category 3  Category 4  Category 5  Category 6
            box1            x   
            box2            x   
            box3            x   
            box4            x   
            box5            x
```

file 2

```
name                                        id
job                                     number
address                                 none    
address                                 xyz 
address                                 date    
            company name                            
            quarter report                          
            date                            
Group   Manager     quarter1    quarter2    quarter3    quarter4                total
element2    A           $          $           $           $                      $
notElement  B           $          $           $           $                      $
card3       C           $          $           $           $                      $
box4        D           $          $           $           $                      $
element3    E           $          $           $           $                      $
box1        F           $          $           $           $                      $
notElement  B           $          $           $           $                      $
notElement  C           $          $           $           $                      $             
card7       D           $          $           $           $                      $
element4    E           $          $           $           $                      $
                                        
               quarter1 quarter2 quarter3 quarter4                      
average           $        $                                
results          none     none                              
missed                     1                                
missed                     1
```

desired csv file:

```
Group   Manager     quarter1    quarter2    quarter3    quarter4                total
element2    A           $          $           $           $                      $
card3       C           $          $           $           $                      $
box4        D           $          $           $           $                      $
element3    E           $          $           $           $                      $
box1        F           $          $           $           $                      $
card7       D           $          $           $           $                      $
element4    E           $          $           $           $                      $
```

Comment: What is your problem? How do the parsed dataframes look like? What is your current result? Why is it not good?

Comment: sorry about that. i should have been more clear. i also didn't update the code properly, but i tried to clarify it in the post now. please let me know if it's not clear still. thank you

Comment: now you deleted all code pertaining to pandas?  Your base file data is ill suited to be read using either - you would have to do some skipping of header lines to parse them successfully - the csvs - do they use spaces as seperators between columns? Your code does nothing to try to "fix" the bad format your files use so and comparing whole "lines" does nothing to find one columns worth of data etc.

Comment: for a "line based approach" : read file 1 line by line, skip all lines that come before  one that starts with "Category". Read all lines until you hit a line that starts with "List " + Number and split them at your dividing character and store into a list. Skip all lines till you find one with category etc. until end. From the stored list of list extract all the 2nd inner list element as Category 2. From file 2 read all lines, keep the header line starting with "Group Manager .." and keep all other lines that start with anything you just extracted and ignore the rest. Happy Coding.